# Meteor Router.go not changing Url even though page transitions

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am having a very strange error. I have a click event setup for a button, and it sends to another template through Router.go. However, the page will transition, and it will pass the data, but the url doesn't change. So I can't use the params for the next transition (this is for a signup flow).

```
Template.tellUsAboutYourself.events({


'click .continueHide': function(){
    var mealsPerDay = $('.checkbox_check1:checked').val();
    var snacksPerDay = $('.checkbox_check2:checked').val();
    var typesOfSnacks = '';
    $('.checkbox_check3:checked').each(function(i){
      typesOfSnacks = typesOfSnacks + '4' + $(this).val();
    });
    var homeCooked = $('.checkbox_check4:checked').val();
    var sodaOften = $('.checkbox_check5:checked').val();
    var coffeeOften = $('.checkbox_check6:checked').val();
    var coffeeHow = $('.checkbox_check6a:checked').val();
    var juiceOften = $('.checkbox_check7:checked').val();
    var threeFoodsOften = '';
    $('.checkbox_check8:checked').each(function(i){
      threeFoodsOften = threeFoodsOften + '4' + $(this).val();
    });
    var activityLevel = $('.checkbox_check9:checked').val();

    var id = NutritionData.insert({name: this.name, last_name: this.last_name, ideal_weight: this.ideal_weight, height: this.height, current_weight: this.current_weight, gender: this.gender, age: this.age, mealsPerDay: mealsPerDay, snacksPerDay: snacksPerDay, typesOfSnacks: typesOfSnacks, homeCooked: homeCooked, sodaOften: sodaOften, coffeeOften: coffeeOften, coffeeHow: coffeeHow, juiceOften: juiceOften, threeFoodsOften: threeFoodsOften, activityLevel: activityLevel});
    console.log(id);

    Router.go('yourResults', {id: id});
  }
});
```

And then in the router.js file I have the following:

```
Router.route('/yourResults/:id', {
  name: 'yourResults',
  trackPageView: true,
  layoutTemplate: false,
  data: function(){
    return NutritionData.find({_id: this.params.id}).fetch()[0]
  },
});
```

The ID is correct, but for some reason it's not changing the url. Has anyone had this problem before? I have been refactoring tons of my code looking everywhere for an error but I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks

Comment: In your route shouldn't `layoutTemplate` be a string instead of `false`?

Comment: No this is not the issue, I use this for many other templates.. and I did remove it to see if it was it, but the problem persists. But still thank you for your response.

Comment: By the way, you can use NutritionData.findOne(this.params.id) instead of NutritionData.find({_id: this.params.id}).fetch()[0] - that way will be a lil bit shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: is it works `yourResults/id` in browser url?

Comment: yeah if I enter it manually it works fine

Comment: and thanks @naneri I made that change already

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it had nothing to do with the router. Just in the rare case anyone would run into the same nightmare scenario, the error was due to a session variable that was inside a for loop inside a helper that particularly ran many times. This was not giving any errors but it was causing all sorts of weird behaviors, including router malfunction.